# Not able to start kafka server as it gives wmic error but my zookeeper is working fine

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

**Not able to start kafka server but my zookeeper is working fine**

C:\kafka> .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
**The system cannot find the path specified.**

C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

version of kafka is 3.0.0 latest

Answer (score 0):

back slash() is missing before **bin**.

try this:

C:\kafka> .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

Comment: now got this......................................................................................................................  C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: which windows version you are using ? Did u check platform requirements to install kafka3.0?